# ls: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, ls

I have been messing around trying to install macvim to a higher version of 7.4. I finally got it working but now I get the error

```
ls: No such file or directory
```

when looking for a directory. I can temporarily fix it by using the command

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

however, as soon as I exit my terminal window the problem returns. How do I fix this permanently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the following to your ~/.bash_profile file so the PATH is loaded every time you log in:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```